# Typescript React how to store an Object permanently

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, typescript, device-orientation

Good day,

I am coding a compass application in react and have some problems.

I am working with a DeviceOrientationEvent, if i add an EventListener it orientates to the device heading, not to the absolute earth heading.

My idea is, to display a calibration button, the user has to orientate his phone to north (deviceheading === absolute earth heading) and then press the button.

Here a code example:

```
calibrationButtonOnClick() //Method which is executed when pressing the calibration button
{
   orientationHandler = await Motion.addListener("orientation", (event:any) => {orientationChange(event)});

//The orientationHandler object i want to store permanent.
}
```

If the button get pressed, i set the orientation event listener and get a DeviceOrientationEvent which points to north.

My problem: If i restart the application i have to calibrate the app new.

My idea:  Calibrate it once and than store the "DeviceOrientationEvent" instance permanently. After restarting i can load and use it.

Have you some idea how i can store an object instance?

I´ll publish the application as android app

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make use of [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the data.

Comment: Thanks i#ll try to use it. So if i store an object with an event trigger, the event will fire after loading it from local storage ?